# DNG/RAW-image: What's the difference between DefaultCropSize and ActiveArea?

Tags: android, matlab, android-camera2, dng

We have a Google Nexus 5 which takes RAW images in DNG-format. We were wondering where the difference of the DefaultCropSize (2448x3264) and ActiveArea (2464x3280) comes from and whether these pixels are used for some kind of black-level compensation or so?
I've read that there are chances, that there is a masking layer over some of the pixels to get "online"-darkvalues. Could that be the issue here?

We're reading the files in MATLAB using this method which works quiet well:
https://github.com/rcsumner/devCam/blob/5ab896704fdced674bfed8767c90251ce2cebe06/MATLAB/dngRead.m

The Adobe-DNG documentation gives these details: 
http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/dng_spec.pdf

> Defaul Crop Size:
>
> Raw images often store extra pixels around the edges of the final
>   image. These extra pixels help prevent interpolation artifacts near
>   the edges of the final image. DefaultCropSize specifies the size of
>   the final image area, in raw image coordinates (i.e., before the
>   DefaultScale has been applied).
>
> Active Area:
>
> This rectangle defines the active (non-masked) pixels of the sensor.
>   The order of the rectangle coordinates is: top, left, bottom, right.

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: The difference: 8 pixels all around, as per the documentation comments you've posted these are the extra pixels which are masked for Default Crop Size but within the non-masked Active Area...

Comment: Does this mean, that there is a "mechanical" layer on the pixels which allows us to have a mask for dark-current measurements? When I observe it with MATLAB or so it's not black at all.

Answer (score 1):

DNG specifies 4 crops

1. **Full sensor**: all available data, including masked pixels
2. **ActiveArea**: useful data, excludes masked pixels
3. **DefaultCropOrigin/Size**: picture area to be used (i.e., what the JPG-version of the picture would be)
4. **DefaultUserCrop** (since 1.4): further crop-area based on user config (e.g., for 16:9-mode of some cameras or digital zoom)

Most cameras leave a small band (8 pixels in your case) between the DefaulCrop and the ActiveArea. Main reason for this is that the extra pixels are required for de-mosaicing of the picture (if you de-mosaic the ActiveArea, you are missing 'neighbour-pixels' at the edges).